# Control multiple tv(lcd) with a smartPhone (Android/iOs) via Google Cast SDK

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, google-cast

I wanna build a app control multiple tv (lcd) with a smartphone (Android/iOs) via Google Cast SDK and ChromeCast . With This App, we  will play video A on Tv1 (Chromecast 1) , and display images on TV2 (Chromecast 2) , and  open the browser on TV3 (Chromecast 3), etc .We will controll all of them on a screen Smartphone .
So Can I build a App via google Cast SDK and chromecast for do it ?
Tks . 
p.s : Sorry my English too bad .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast SDK supports connection and control of one device at a time. You can connect to the first device and launch your first app and then disconnect from that device and connect to the second device and launch the second app, etc. Receivers should be built so that a disconnect doesn't tear them down.

Comment: if I disconnect from the first device , My TV will play continuous video ?

Comment: Depends on your receiver application; the logic in your receiver decides to continue on playing even if all connected devices disconnect themselves, or stop playing. That logic is in onSenderDisconnected() (on the receiver side).

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping